# StreamWriter - Não pode acessar o arquivo porque esta sendo usado por outro processo

Tags: vb.net, stream-de-arquivos

Galera tenho o seguinte código abaixo que quando executado ele sempre me retorna o erro de que esta sendo usado por outro processo. Garanto que não há outro processo aberto com ele!

```vb-net
#Region "Declaração DLL"
    Dim ServerMaster As ServiceNetwork_ServerMasterSecurity
#End Region

#Region "Escritor"

#End Region

#Region "Declaração De String's"
    Dim LocalAPPProc As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Server Master\AntiDebugger\Cache Process Kill"
#End Region

#Region "Date"
    Dim Data As DateTime = Date.Now
#End Region

    Public Sub IniciarProcessoFolder()
        If Directory.Exists(LocalAPPProc & "\" & Data.Year) Then
            VerificarSubPastas()
        Else
            Directory.CreateDirectory(LocalAPPProc & "\" & Data.Year)
            IniciarProcessoFolder()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub VerificarSubPastas()
        Dim Local As String = LocalAPPProc & "\" & Data.Year.ToString()
        Dim MesFolder As Integer = 12

        For i As Integer = 1 To MesFolder

            If Directory.Exists(Local & "\" & i) Then
                i += 1
            Else
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Local & "\" & i)
                Thread.Sleep(20)
            End If

            If i = 12 Then
                VerificarStringProcess()

            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub VerificarStringProcess()
        Dim LerProcessKill As String() = File.ReadAllLines(LocalAPPProc & "\ProcKill.lg")

        ''Primeiro Verificar Se Tem Alguma String
        If LerProcessKill(0) <> "" Then

            EscreverProcesso()

        Else

            MsgBox("O Processo não pode ser gravado no cache por não conter string valida.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "AntiDebuggers")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub EscreverProcesso()
        Dim Dia As String = Data.DayOfWeek
        Dim Mes As String = Data.Month.ToString()
        Dim Ano As String = Data.Year.ToString()
        Dim Hora As String = Data.Hour & "." & Data.Minute.ToString()
        Dim Seconds As String = Data.Second.ToString()

        Dim DateComplete As String = Dia & "." & Mes & "." & Ano & "." & Hora & "." & Seconds & ".log"

        Dim LC As String = LocalAPPProc & "\" & Ano & "\"

        If Directory.Exists(LocalAPPProc & "\" & Data.Year) Then

            ''Cria o arquivo de log 
            File.CreateText(LC & Mes & "\" & DateComplete)

            ''Chama o escritor
            Escreve()
        Else
            MsgBox("A Pasta de log's não existe.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "AntiDebuggers:0x003")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Escreve()
        Dim Dia As String = Data.DayOfWeek
        Dim Mes As String = Data.Month.ToString()
        Dim Ano As String = Data.Year.ToString()
        Dim Hora As String = Data.Hour & "." & Data.Minute.ToString()
        Dim Seconds As String = Data.Second.ToString(0)


        Dim LC As String = LocalAPPProc & "\" & Ano & "\"
        Dim DateComplete As String = Dia & "." & Mes & "." & Ano & "." & Hora & "." & Seconds & ".log"
        Dim Escritor As StreamWriter
        Escritor = New StreamWriter(LC & Mes & "\" & DateComplete) ''<< Aqui é o problema
        Dim ProcessKill As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\Server Master\AntiDebugger\Cache Process Kill\ProcKill.lg")


        Escritor.WriteLine("Process Kill:   " & ProcessKill(0))
        Escritor.WriteLine("Date Kill: " & Date.Now)
        Escritor.Close()

        ''Reinicia o timer do server master
        '   Dim Serv As New ServiceNetwork_ServerMasterSecurity

        ' Serv.TAntiDebugger.Start()
    End Sub
```

O problema ocorre quando eu declaro uma nova Instancia no `StreamWriter`.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato não há outro processo usando o arquivo, é o teu próprio programa.

O problema ocorre no método `EscreverProcesso`:

```all
Private Sub EscreverProcesso()
   ' ....
   If Directory.Exists(LocalAPPProc & "\" & Data.Year) Then
        File.CreateText(LC & Mes & "\" & DateComplete)
        ' Aqui é necessário você fechar o objeto do StreamWriter!
        ' ...
        Escreve() ' Quando você chama este método, ocasiona o erro!
        ' ....
   End If
End Sub
```

Para resolver, no código acima substitua a linha:

```vb-net
File.CreateText(LC & Mes & "\" & DateComplete)
```

Por estas linhas:

```vb-net
Dim sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(LC & Mes & "\" & DateComplete)
sw.Close()
```

Sempre quando você for abrir um arquivo, seja para *leitura* ou *escrita*, é necessário fechar o objeto identificador com o [método `StreamWriter.Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Muito Obrigado!! Realmente eu nunca pensei que seria por isso.. eu pensava que esse metodo não ocupava o arquivo assim..